# Multiple errors while running flutter for desktop in Linux

Tags: linux, flutter, desktop-application, flutter-dependencies

https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-for-desktop-create-and-run-a-desktop-application-ebeb1604f1e0

While following this article for running flutter on a desktop I'm getting the following errors:

make: pkg-config: Command not found
make: clang++: Command not found
make: *** [/home/hachiman69/Flutter/flutter-desktop-embedding/testbed/linux/../build/linux/obj/debug/main.o] Error 127

Answer (score 0):

Those aren't official instructions, and they are both incomplete and mostly obsolete. Per the [official instructions](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Desktop-shells#tooling) you need to run `flutter doctor` to find out if you have all the tools you need, installing anything that is missing.